# How to use Gecko with C++ and QT

Tags: c++, qt, gecko

I would like to know how I can use Gecko with Qt and C++. I'm making my own Webbrowser and I am stuck with this Question. As Operation System I use Windows 10.

Comment: QtMozembed, I guess. There's a fork from Jolla for their Sailfish phones, and they are still maintaining it.